# Ruby interface classes?

Tags: ruby, oop

I have the following classes:

```
CachedObject
CachedObjectSource
CachedObjectDbSource < CachedObjectSource
CachedObjectDalliSource < CachedObjectSource
```

CachedObject is a non-database object that is getting pulled from a third-party API and stored locally.  CachedObject will be stored in both the database and Dalli (memcache), the real-time code will ping the Dalli source for a copy of the object, and the Dalli source will search the database source and update its cache if the object does not exist.  So it's a nested call that requires each child class of CachedObjectSource to implement the same set of methods.  IE, an interface.

Is there a way to write the CachedObjectSource class so that its child classes must implement the interface?  Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I think the Ruby philosophy is against static checks for interfaces in a class definition. If you want to be sure that children of `CachedObjectSource` implement the same methods, maybe the Ruby way is to write a unit test that contains a list of expected methods, and verifies that an instance of each type of source `responds_to?` each method in the list.

Comment: @RoryO'Kane Of course, the unit test approach fails if "each type of source" isn't deterministic. (Like if it can be loaded from plugins.) It'd be more appropriate for the implementations themselves to be tested anyway.

Comment: You could add a testing helper which can easily be included to test the validity of child classes, similar to what is e.g. available [for ActiveModel](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/lint.rb)

Comment: Here's a nice blog post about how to handle the concept of interfaces through unit tests. https://morningcoffee.io/interfaces-in-ruby.html

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ruby doesn't know interfaces similar to e.g. Java. Instead, Ruby programs typically use an approach called [Duck Typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) which basically means that you can send any message to any object which then can decide if it will respond to that, i.e. each object decides on its own which methods it has.

The closest thing you can get to an "interface" is a class (or module) that implements a method but only raises a `NotImplementedError` similar to this:

```
class CachedObjectSource
  def my_method
    raise NotImplementedError, "Implement this method in a child class"
  end
end
```

That way, the method will be present and return a sensible error when called without being overwritten in a child class. Then, you should write some documentation making it clear what child classes have to implement to be compliant.

Comment: You can also not implement the method by not implementing it, which produces the same sort of error. Ruby tends to lean much more heavily on unit testing to expose problems like this than other languages because the language itself doesn't have any strict checks.

Comment: Sure, in the end, it's just an additional hint that there should be a method implemented, a `NoMethodError` has by default the same meaning as `NotImplementedError`. However, users of the class can see it in the code what they need to implement and get a clearer error message. In the end, it's more or less the question of explicit vs implicit (while I lean more to the explicit side of things).

Comment: if you like to give some more information about the method that has to be implemented, I like to use the following line: `fail NotImplementedError, "#{self.class}##{__method__} method must be implemented"`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the gem [interface](https://rubygems.org/gems/interface).
This gem emulates interfaces similar to Java interfaces.
For example:

```
require 'interface'

MyInterface = interface{
  required_methods :foo, :bar, :baz
}

# Raises an error until 'baz' is defined
class MyClass
  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end

  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end

  implements MyInterface
end
```

This gem which is useful together with [abstract](https://rubygems.org/gems/abstract) gem.
Abstract gem provides abstract methods.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [rint](https://rubygems.org/gems/rint)

`gem 'rint'`

that comes with a CLI:

`$ rint c CachedObjectSourceInterface my_method`

will create an interface definition, but you can also add it manually to any class. Then you can do something like:

```
class Instrument 
  implements CachedObjectSourceInterface
end
```

and it will throw a meaningful Exception if the method `my_method` is not implemented.